# How do I style the 'label' of each checkbox generated by Simple_Form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

This:

```
<%= f.input :accomplished_goal, label: "Accomplished goal this week?", collection: ["Yes", "No"], as: :check_boxes, label_html: { class: 'checkbox inline' } %>
```

Produces:

```
<div class="control-group check_boxes optional weekly_entry_accomplished_goal">
   <label class="check_boxes optional control-label checkbox inline">Accomplished goal this week?</label>
    <div class="controls">
       <label class="checkbox">
           <input class="check_boxes optional" id="weekly_entry_accomplished_goal_yes" name="weekly_entry[accomplished_goal][]" type="checkbox" value="Yes" />
             Yes
       </label>
       <label class="checkbox">
           <input class="check_boxes optional" id="weekly_entry_accomplished_goal_no" name="weekly_entry[accomplished_goal][]" type="checkbox" value="No" />
              No
       </label>
           <input name="weekly_entry[accomplished_goal][]" type="hidden" value="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Ideally, I would like to add the style `inline` to the inner `label class="checkbox"`

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I found works:

```
<%= f.input :accomplished_goal, label: "Accomplished goal this week?", collection: ["Yes", "No"], as: :check_boxes, item_wrapper_class: 'inline' %>
```

i.e. using the attribute `item_wrapper_class: 'inline'`

Adds the class `inline` to the internal `<label class="checkbox inline">`